# Xamarin.Swift4.* and Linking on iOs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I used the following guide in order to bind a Swift Library:

https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76

This technique requires to reference several nuget Packages for Swift support.
Its is working however referencing Xamarin.Swift4.Core and Xamarin.Swift4.Foundation adds ~50MB to an empty Xamarin Forms app even with the "Link All" option activated (with LLVM too)...

Is there a solution to make linker do its job correctly for this library?

Did someone found a workaround to this issue?

Comment: do you mean 50mb?

Comment: 50MB (Mo in French)

Comment: Well, in that case, I guess you have covered everything there is nothing else that you can do to make the size of your .IPA smaller at least in my knowledge

Comment: Did someone already bound a Swift Library?

Comment: I don't think so why do you need it anyway?

Comment: The Mono Linker only strips CIL, not native code. The remaining CIL code after linking is than AOT'd. And yes, there are 3rd-party Swift Nuget Packages that include the Swift libraries as embedded frameworks but they are not Xamarin.iOS "bound".

Comment: Thanks for explanations. Perhaps you have more information. Nuget Swift not for Xamarin iOs (i know that nuget can be used for everything but with Swift)?

Comment: I'm very surprised that nobody else complains about the size problem with this technique

Comment: Do not include them all as dependency in your project as it will increase the final App size. Use just what you need.